# Asymptotics for $\sum_{p<x} \log \log(p)$

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I would like what is the asymptotic behaviour of
$$f(x) := \sum_{p<x} \log\left(\log(p)\right),$$
as $x \to +\infty$,
where the sum runs over prime numbers. It is well-known, by the prime number theorem, that $\sum_{p<x} \log(p) \sim x$. But here the extra log would require to study $\prod_{p<x} \log(p)$, and I don't known how to deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be the characteristic function that determines if $n$ is a prime. Then
$$\sum_{p\leqslant x}\log\log p=\sum_{n\leqslant x}\alpha(n)\log\log n$$
By Abel's formula we have
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\leqslant x}\alpha(n)\log\log n
&=\log\log 2+\sum_{2<n\leqslant x}\alpha(n)\log\log n\\
&=\log\log 2+A(x)\log\log x-\log\log 2-\int_2^x\frac{A(t)}{t\log t}dt\\
&=\pi(x)\log\log x+O\left(\int_2^x\frac{t}{t\log t}dt\right)\\
&=\pi(x)\log\log x+O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)
\end{align*}$$
where $A(x)=\sum_{n\leqslant x}\alpha(n)$.

---

This can be slightly improved if we write $A(x)=\pi(x)=O(x/\log x)$ instead of $O(x)$. This will give us
$$\sum_{n\leqslant x}\alpha(n)\log\log n=\pi(x)\log\log x+O\left(\int_2^x\frac{1}{\log^2 t}dt\right)$$
where the integral is dominated by $\operatorname{li}(x)-\frac{x}{\log x}=O\left(\frac{x}{\log^2 x}\right)$.

Comment: I am not sure if this is good enough for you. If this formula is not good enough, I will delete my post.

Comment: Yourong No need to delete, it can still be interesting to others.

Comment: @Milten cool...

Comment: To obtain a precise asymptotics for the product, you would need an asymptotics for the sum with an error of $o(1)$ at least. Even under the RH, the error term would be $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})$. Of course, you can use the explicit formula for $\pi(x)$ but that does not yield a simple asymptotic formula.

Comment: @Gary that is correct. This asymptotic formula is quite trivial actually. I asked the OP if it's good enough and it seemed to be ok.